# Laravel Mongo DB belongsToMany from ids

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-mongodb

This is a Laravel / Mongo DB questions. I've got two models that are on mongo db.

### Model 1 > Task

```
{
  "user_ids": [
       "id_1",
       "id_2",
   ]
}
```

Then my model two

### Model 2 > User

```
{
  "_id": "id"
}
```

Now from my Model 1 (Task), I want to create a belongsToMany relationship so I can use the `protected $with` to fetch the objects in one go.

I have this in my Model 1 class

```
class Task extends Model
{

   protected $with = [
      'users'
   ];

   public function users()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(
         User::class,
         null,
         '_id',
         'user_ids'
      )
   }

}
```

Now is the interesting bit. So it returns the object and an empty array for users. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Okay did a lot of look around ad dived into the vendor folders to figure out you cant actually do it.

The thing is with the references it ends up sending a multi-dimensional array which ends up breaking the whereIn function of eloquent.

This may be an area that the relation builder to improve.

What I did was to let it stay as an array and use a second function to query the results based on the ids.